# Can't use String.Contains();

Tags: c#, .net

What I want to do is store the top 500 sites listed on alexa.com into a .txt file. 
Here's how the program works.

When my .net browser visit one of alexa's page, it stores all the links into an html collection.
Then, I use a loop to find out if the link's text contains a "."
If it does, it store the url into a .txt file.

The problem is, `String.Contains();` won't work so, I end storing useless information as well.
Why won't `String.Contains();` work?

Error Message :  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

**Important parts**

Robot.cs

```
public HtmlElementCollection page_elements
{
    get;
    set;
}

public void exec_task()
{
    var url_to_txtfile = new StreamWriter("urls.txt", true);

    foreach (HtmlElement element in page_elements)
    {
        string element_text = element.InnerText;
        if (element_text.Contains(".")) // Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
            url_to_txtfile.WriteLine(element_text);
    }

    url_to_txtfile.Close();

    next_page();
}
```

Form1.cs

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Bot.page_elements = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");
    Bot.pages_visited++;

    if (Bot.pages_visited <= Bot.pages_to_visit)
    {
        Bot.exec_task();
        webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(Bot.url);
    }

}
```

**Source Code**

Robot.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AlexaBot
{
    class Robot
    {

        public Robot(string link, byte pages, byte items)
        {
            url = link;

            pages_to_visit = pages;
            link_per_page = items;

            pages_visited = -1;
        }

        public byte pages_to_visit
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        private byte link_per_page
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public sbyte pages_visited
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string url
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public HtmlElementCollection page_elements
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public void exec_task()
        {
            var url_to_txtfile = new StreamWriter("urls.txt", true);

            foreach (HtmlElement element in page_elements)
            {
                string element_text = element.InnerText;
                if (element_text.Contains("."))
                    url_to_txtfile.WriteLine(element_text);
            }

            url_to_txtfile.Close();

            next_page();
        }

        private void next_page()
        {
            if (pages_visited < 11)
                url = url.Remove(url.Length - 1) + pages_visited.ToString();
            else
                url = url.Remove(url.Length - 2) + pages_visited.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AlexaBot
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Robot Bot;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Bot = new Robot("http://www.alexa.com/topsites/global;0", 20, 25);
            webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(Bot.url);
        }

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            Bot.page_elements = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");
            Bot.pages_visited++;

            if (Bot.pages_visited <= Bot.pages_to_visit)
            {
                Bot.exec_task();
                webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(Bot.url);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`string.Contains()` works just fine.  The error is telling you that your object is `null`, and you can't dereference a `null` object.  So in this line:

```
if (element_text.Contains("."))
```

clearly `element_text` is `null`.  You should wrap it in a null check, maybe something as simple as this:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(element_text))
    if (element_text.Contains("."))
```

(Or, for older versions of .NET, use `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` instead.)

`page_elements` probably contains *a lot* of HTML elements, not all of which have an `InnerText` value.  Those that don't will be `null`.  There's probably additional filtering you can do here to narrow your search, including using a more mature DOM parser (as mentioned in a comment on the question).